# If $f(x),f'(x),f''(x)$ are in GP and $f(0)=1,f'(0)=1,$then

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ be a non-zero function whose all successive derivatives exist and are non-zero.If $f(x),f'(x),f''(x)$ are in GP and $f(0)=1,f'(0)=1,$then
$(A)f'(x)<0\forall x\in R$
$(B)f''(x)<1\forall x\in R$
$(C)f''(0)\ne f'''(0)$
$(D)f''(x)>0\forall x\in R$

---

$[f'(x)]^2=f(x)f''(x)$ as they are in $GP$,now i dont know how to identify correct options.

Comment: (A) and (B) seem to be false when $x=0$

Comment: A solution is $f(x)=e^x$

Comment: @Henry but it would be better if you told how you came up with that solution.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar - it seemed rather obvious as a solution to $f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=1$. It clearly also satisfies $f(x)f''(x)=(f'(x))^2$. Donald Splutterwit has shown it is the only solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We require the $f(x),f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ to be in geometric progression. So (as the OP states) we need $(f'(x))^2=f(x)f''(x)$. We shall change notation to $y=f(x)$ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2 = y \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
This is easily solved by the usual trick ... let $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$ then $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=p \frac{dp}{dy}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
p=y \frac{dp}{dy} \\
\ln (p)= \ln(y) +\ln(B) \\ 
B y= \frac{dy}{dx} \\
y=A e^{Bx}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now using the initial conditions $f(0)=1,f'(0)=1$ we have $ \color{red}{f(x)=e^x}$ as stated by Henry.

Comment: Shouldn't those $\dfrac{dx}{dy}$'s be $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$'s?

Comment: @TonyK You are right. Thanks for bring it to my attention. I have edited now.